# What happens, if you overwrite an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have for example two arrays:

```
float a[][] = new float[3][3];
float b[][] = new float[7][7];
```

I am wondering what happens, if you now write a = b; 
What happens to all the values in a? What length does array a have now? Which values does it have?

Comment: Did you try to just see what happens?

Comment: Have you tried to write `a = b` and see what happened before asking this question?

Comment: Voting to close, we don't encourage questions that shows no efforts.

Answer (score 1):

After the assignment, `a` would refer to the same object as `b`, and therefore its length would be 7 and it would have the values of that array.

If there is no other reference to the original array that was referred to by `a`, it would become eligible for garbage collection. Otherwise, that array would continue to exist.

Arrays in Java behave exactly the same as any other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Internally this will happen
`float a[][] = new float[3][3];`
an array object is created and assigned to a

`float b[][] = new float[7][7];` an array object is created and assigned to b

`a=b` 'b' object is assigned to a, now a and b pointing to same array object and a's previous object is eligible for garbage collection.